# Why does Object.assign not work when es2015 preset installed with babel 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using the react, es2015 and stage-0 presets in my project which I thought installed all the transforms I'd need for ES6 but apparently not. When testing on IE9 I get Object.assign and String.includes are not methods.

My .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-display-name"
  ]
}
```

Comment: When googling babel object.assign not working that other answer didn't show so I assumed there wasn't one.

Comment: That's OK, I included "babel-polyfill" in my search which is how I found it :)

Comment: Searching the answer isn't what people tend to do :P. Maybe people will search google, come here and find the answer on the dupe you marked :)